# Tell me the solution to the simple grammatical errors of Android Studios

Tags: java, android

public void onClick (View v) {

There is a simple grammatical error in this area and I don't know how to solve it.

i don't know sorry

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyView view = new MyView();

    public void onClick (View v) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn :
                view.isDraw = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

MyView class

```
public class MyView extends View {

public boolean isDraw = false;

public MyView() {
    super(context);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(500);
int y = random.nextInt(800);

int r = (random.nextInt(3)+1) * 100;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    isDraw = false;
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    Paint Pnt = new Paint();
    Pnt.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    if(isDraw == true) {
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y,r,Pnt);
    }
}
}
```

I want to draw a circle on the coordinates of the random value when I press the button.

Comment: How do you know you have an error?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: "simple grammatical error" isn't *specific* enough to let others with same problem find your question and potential answer to it (which is *main* goal of this site). Use [edit] option and provide exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a void on your `onCreate`. Try to put it outside.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyView view = new MyView();


}
public void onClick (View v) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn :
                view.isDraw = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to draw a circle on the coordinates of the random value when I press the button.

If you want to do that, first, you need to find your button using `findViewById` an example coulld be :

```
private Button myButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myButton = findViewById(R.id.IdfromActivity_main);
}
```

Then if you want to make an `onClickListener` there are [multiple ways to do this](https://medium.com/@CodyEngel/4-ways-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android-9b956cbd2928).

In your code an example could be :

```
private Button myButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myButton = findViewById(R.id.IdfromActivity_main);
    MyView view = new MyView();
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button clicked!",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Add whatever action you need
        }
    });
}
```

And then you have also an error, that you have a method inside another method, let's say you have inside the `onCreate` method `onClick` method, so you should split them and put it outside of this `onCreate` method.